# Game where you win if you get heads and the other player gets tails

Tags: probability

Two players $A$ and  $B$ toss a coin. A has a coin $C_A$, B has a coin $C_B$.
Probability of tail for $C_A = 1-a$, of head: $C_A = a$
Similary for $C_B$.
Now, they are tossing on turn. The A starts. The winner is player which as first get a head while the second player get a tail.

For example:

TTTTHHHHTTHHTH   ( results, H is head, T is tail) for

ABABABABABABAB   ( they toss on turn)

And B won. 
Why?
Because he get H while A get T.

What is a probability that B win?

Please give me a hint.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Please give me a hint.

Comment: But what is the question you want a hint about? Is it the probability that A wins?

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: When you say "similarly for $C_B$" do you mean probability of a head is $a$ again, or do you mean it is $b$ (because $b$ is a lower-case $B$)? Also, from the example, it seems $A$ does not win if $B$ tosses tails and then $A$ tosses heads, but only if $A$ tosses heads and then $B$ tosses tails, is that right?

Answer (score 1):

Who's on first? :-)

**Hint.** The game ends when either

- $A$ flips heads while $B$ flips tails (probability $a(1-b)$), in which case $A$ wins; or
- $B$ flips heads while $A$ flips tails (probability $b(1-a)$), in which case $B$ wins

These events are disjoint (that is, mutually exclusive), so the probability that either one happens is just the sum of their individual probabilities.  The $HH$ and $TT$ events merely prolong the game and therefore do not affect the distribution of events that end the game.

Then ask yourself, what is the probability, *given that the game ends*, that $A$ wins on that turn?  What is the probability, *given that the game ends*, that $B$ wins on that turn?  Those probabilities should add up to $1$, and are the desired probabilities.